# Is there a clean way of using addControl with strongly typed forms?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

If I have a form:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  foo: new FormControl(''),
});
```

and I want to dynamically add a control to it like:

```
form.addControl('bar', new FormControl(''));
```

I get an error which appears to come back to `bar` not being defined in `form`. The error suggests adding it as an optional property. The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol) also says:

> In a strongly-typed group, the control must be in the group's type (possibly as an optional key).

It seems I could add it in two ways:

1. Explicitly specify the complete Form model in the generic parameter of `FormGroup`, containing the optional `bar` property. I don't want to do this as in reality it is a large and complex object.

```
const form = new FormGroup<{ foo: string, bar?: string }>({
  ...
});
```

2. declare `bar` as an optional property in the `FormGroup` object parameter, but it looks like I need to declare the associated `FormControl` value with it, which means it is already in the form (I want to start without it)

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  foo: new FormControl(''),
  bar?: new FormControl('')
});
```

It seems contradictory that I need to add a `FormControl` that I in fact want to add dynamically.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsu9at?file=src%2Fadd-control.ts

Comment: If you define a form group in an exported class, you can add new form control to it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mmqmwy

Comment: That only works because you are using Angular 13 where FormGroup (nor the form module in general) is not typed.

Comment: Hm you're right. The first thing that comes to mind is to type the form when initializing it (`form: FormGroup`) and adding controls, then when you need to add new control - you set `this.form = null` and rebuild it again, this time with new control in it, and so on. Of course, you'd have to keep the already inserted values. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpxzg8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have thought about this more and from a typing perspective it makes sense that you have to use one of the two methods given in the question - ultimately the type of the form model must be known or inferable to satisfy the form modules typing behavior.

From the Angular docs, [`FormRecord`](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formrecord) has been added as a substitute for `FormGroup` to deal with this situation:

> Some FormGroup usages do not fit the above pattern because the keys are not known ahead of time. The FormRecord class is designed for that case

However it has typing limitations which would work in the example I gave as both properties are strings, but not in my real world example where they are different.

> If you need a FormGroup that is both dynamic (open-ended) and heterogeneous (the controls are different types), no improved type safety is possible, and you should use UntypedFormGroup.

Another possibility is adding the control in the initial declaration, but setting it disabled which means it will not be present in `form.value`:

```
 const form = new FormGroup({
    foo: new FormControl('foo'),
    bar: new FormControl({ value: 'bar', disabled: true }),
  });
```

Subsequently calling `form.controls.bar.enable()` rather than `form.addControl(..)` will result in `bar` being present in `form.value`.

Stackblitz showing this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e58odo?file=src%2Fadd-control.ts,src%2Fmain.ts